# Make assembly from SQL 2016 work in SQL 2017 (ex: Calling Math Parser from SQL Server 2017)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a stored procedure that needs some complex math expression evaluation.
There is a formula and this stored procedure evaluates its value.

It calls an UDF defined as below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfComputeMath]
    (@inputString [NVARCHAR](MAX))
RETURNS [NVARCHAR](4000) 
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [SMP_Assembly].[SuperMathParser.MathParser].[ComputeMath]
```

This is quite old code, it worked just fine since SQL Server 2008 R2 (at least), up to 2016.

However now we try to update our DB to SQL Server 2017, and this no longer works.

I get the following error:

> Msg 10314, Level 16, State 11, Procedure GetPermitTypeFeesByPermitID, Line 88 [Batch Start Line 0]
> An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65536. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error:
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'supermathparser, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An error relating to security occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013150A) System.IO.FileLoadException:
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)

Any idea how can make this work again in SQL Server 2017?

Thank you

Comment: You may need to rebuild your external assembly and target it for sql2017. What I've been noticing with the Sql server stack is that while Microsoft's code is generally backwards compatible, 3rd party extensions and assemblies are not.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However ... I have no special assembly installed. All this worked with SQL 2008 - 2016 out of the box - simply by installing it. So I don't know what assembly might be used for this and why it fails  in 2017 when it worked just fine in 2016.

Comment: `[SMP_Assembly].[SuperMathParser.MathParser].[ComputeMath]` is the external assembly. You can see that in your first code block.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/clr-strict-security
  This seems relevant. It appears clr trust changed in 2017. Going by the error message, I'd look into trust issues first as a possible culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption is that the database where you try to call this on has just been restored to a SQL Server 2017 database, is that correct? If so, the function you try to call is either developed by yourself (company) or is a third party assembly - it is not a built-in MS assembly (the assembly id - 65536 - indicates this as well).

My guess is that the problem is what digital.aaron points to in his comments, it has to do with the changed CLR security model in SQL Server 2017. You can read more about it in [this blogpost](http://www.nielsberglund.com/2017/07/02/sql-server-2017-sqlclr-and-permissions/), and [here](http://www.nielsberglund.com/2017/07/23/sql-server-2017-sqlclr-white-listing-assemblies/) a way to easily:ish fix it.

Hope this helps!

Niels

Comment: Your post pointed me to the right direction to solve the issue.  Thank you all for your time and advices

Comment: This is a link only answer. You should put the relevant sections of your linked blog posts in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Link to "easily fix" does not work and more context would have been more helpful. I ended up going the quick and dirty with the following (run on master):

```
ALTER DATABASE <DatabaseName> SET trustworthy ON
```

The Blog post linked here still works and was very informative